# Android Manifest Xlarge Screen Issue

Tags: android, screen, android-manifest, google-play, screen-size

I had developed an application with the following manifest.

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.test.Test"
    android:versionCode="1111"
    android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="7" android:maxSdkVersion="10"/>
    <supports-screens
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="false"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:anyDensity="true">
    </supports-screens>

    <application android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/KEY_app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <activity android:name=".SplashScreenActivity"
            android:label="@string/KEY_app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
</manifest>
```

---

& default.properties set to `target=android-8`

The concern is that when I deploy the application on android market, by default it displays support to x-large screens as true what should not happen. I tried setting  the x-large screen support to false but it is not supported here. Could you please let me know that how can i set support to x-large screen as false without loosing the support for devices set to lower versions like 2.1 etc.

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Thanks & looking forward to read from you very soon.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

< supports-screens
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="true">
< /supports-screens>

and rest will remain unchanged in Manifest File.